# MVC4 API Routing goes to first action

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am attempting to write an API. The signatures look like this:

```
public class CardsController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ClientData NewGame(){...}
    [HttpGet]
    public ClientData Deal(int sessionId){...}
    [HttpGet]
    public ClientData Stand(int sessionId){...}
}
```

With everything else at default I was getting an error saying my class couldn't differentiate between Deal and Stand. After a bit of research I found it was a routing issue. So I decided to update my routing.

My global.asax.cs now looks like this:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
        AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapHttpRoute("api", "api/{controller}/{action}/{value}", new { value = RouteParameter.Optional});
    }
}
```

Going to `http://localhost:54924/api/Cards/Stand/19` gives an error that says no HttpResource was found, and going to `http://localhost:54924/api/Cards/Stand` triggers the `NewGame()` action. How can I get Stand and Deal to work on the same controller?

Comment: I got an error when I tried your way but this worked for me: http://localhost:54924/api/Cards/Stand?sessionId=19

Comment: @VaibhavDesai Can I see how you have that set? I'm getting the `Multiple actions were found that match the request` error that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the routes:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute("DealApi", 
                    "api/{controller}/deal/{sessionId}",
                    new { action="Deal", sessionId = RouteParameter.Optional });


routes.MapHttpRoute("StandApi", 
                    "api/{controller}/stand/{sessionId}",
                    new { action="Stand", sessionId = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

Now, in your Controller class:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Deal")]
public ClientData Deal(int sessionId){...}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Stand")]
public ClientData Stand(int sessionId){...}
```

Now, whenever you pull up the url http://www.yourhost.com/api/deal/12345, the Deal function will be called. Same thing with Stand.

Keep in mind that whatever you set in your routes tables are only for recognizing whether a url is valid. By having the action specified in the third parameter, you're telling Web Api to find a function whose ActionName attribute is set to what you specify.

Another thing - put those two routes BEFORE any of your default api routes.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've got a better understanding of how routing works now.

Answer (score 3):

Web API works with RESTful routes. In REST you have resources and standard actions with them: GET, POST, PUT, PATCH and DELETE. That's how your actions should be named. `Deal` and `Stand` means absolutely noting in `RESTful` routing. When you are designing an API you should be thinking in terms of resources and the standard HTTP verbs that you could do with those resources. In a RESTful API the controller represents your resource and the HTTP verbs are the actions that you want to perform with this resource.

If you want to violate the default RESTful conventions that are built into the Web Api routing you will have to modify your route setup and include the `{action}` name in it. Then you will be able to name your actions however you want. Just bare in mind that if you are designing an API there are standards that consumers adhere to. If you want to be reinventing wheels make sure you have really good documentation of your API.

Comment: This isn't intended for outside consumption as it's for personal use. I'm not too concerned with documentation outside of my own code comments as a result. As far as including {action} in my route set up, I thought I did?

Comment: Yes, you did it. You also included some `{value}` segment in your routes which is nowhere to be seen in your action arguments. No matter whether your API is publicly visible or not, you should be thinking in terms of RESTful routing. Otherwise you really are missing the whole point of the Web API. If it's for some internal use, just reference the assembly containing the code in the consuming application and don't waste your time with the Web API. You will loose more time for using a technology that's not adapted to your needs rather than doing some useful work.

Comment: I appreciate the lesson. Cheers.